# plotly heatmap cuts y-axis names

Tags: r, plotly

I create a heatmap with plotly with the code below. As you can see in the screenshot attached the y-axis names are not displayed in their full length. I wonder how I will be able to fix this without reducing their font. Is is a solution to bring the heatmap closer to the colorbar or  reduce its width?[image]

```
#data

Database1<-c(1,-2,-3,2,-3,5)
Database2<-c(2,-3,5,2,-3,5)
Database3<-c(3,-5,5,2,-3,5)
Database4<-c(1,-2,-3,2,-3,5)
Database5<-c(2,-3,5,2,-3,5)
Database6<-c(3,-5,5,2,-3,5)
D<-data.frame(Database1,Database2,Database3,Database4,Database5,Database6)
D<-as.matrix(D)
rownames(D)<-c("Database1","Database2","Database3","Database4","Database5","Database6")

#heatmap
library(plotly)
plot_ly(x=colnames(D), y=rownames(D), z = data,colors = colorRamp(c("red","blue")), type = "heatmap",colorbar = list(x = -0.4)) %>%
    layout(
      xaxis=list(tickangle = 45, autorange = "reversed"),
      yaxis = list(side = "right"),
      margin = list(l = 150, r = 50, b = 150, t = 0, pad = 4))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To move `colorbar` closer to heatmap change `colorbar = list(x = ...)`. Here you need position less than 0 (set to `-0.1`). To expand plot to right change `r` in `margin`. Used `150` (the same as for the left margin).

```
library(plotly)
plot_ly(x = colnames(D), y = rownames(D), z = D,
        colors = colorRamp(c("red", "blue")), type = "heatmap",
        colorbar = list(x = -0.1)) %>%
    layout(xaxis = list(tickangle = 45, autorange = "reversed"),
           yaxis = list(side = "right"),
           margin = list(l = 150, r = 150, b = 150, t = 0, pad = 4)
    )
```

[image]